# A terminology for QM calculation methods

Tags: quantum-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, terminology

I wonder if there is any terminology (or name of classification) that refers to ab-initio QM methods based on the Schrodinger equation and basis functions, such as HF and post-HF methods, but not DFT methods. I saw some papers using the term 'wave function theory' or WFT to discriminate it from DFT (and emphasize their higher level of theory), but I want to know if there are other terms.

Comment: DFT methods are also based on the Schrodinger equation and basis functions.

Comment: Thanks @Greg, I tried to mean those not related to density functions but I couldn't come up with proper words for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are often called "wave function-based methods" or, more specifically "wave function-based electron correlation methods" if you want a term for methods beyond Hartree-Fock.

Comment: Also, "post Hartree-Fock". In some contexts, ab initio also doesn't refer to DFT, only HF and post-HF.

Comment: @Hayden I indeed was confused because the term ab initio was quite ambiguous to me (maybe because of my ignorance), since sometimes it seemed not to include DFT methods, even when those weren't (semi-) empirical DFT methods. The term 'Wave function-based methods' looks clear though

Comment: BTW I understood the term "wave function-based electron correlation methods" from @Anyon 's answer as an equivalent to 'post HF'. Am I correct?

Comment: Regarding the discussion of DFT vs ab initio, see [Can DFT be considered an ab initio method?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/518/671), and [Is density functional theory an ab initio method?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33764/98152) on Chem.SE.

Comment: @nonon I don't think the two terms are fully equivalent. In my understanding, the term post-HF sometimes excludes methods using more than one determinant, such as CASSCF, that I don't know very well but would probably argue are still "wave function-based electron correlation methods".